# (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item) always null

Tags: android, searchview, android-actionbar-compat, android-search

i am beginner in android studio and sorry my English is not good.

i have a searchView in secondActivity.
i have done things like below :

1.implemented the `v7 AppCompat` support library in gradle like this **`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'`**
2.implemented `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener`interface for current activity like this **`public class ViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener`**

but the searchView is still null.
below are my source code:

**Menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
       <item
         android:id="@+id/action_search1"
         android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
         app:showAsAction="always"
         app:actionViewClass="android:support.v7.widget.SearchView"
         android:title="@string/search_hint" />
   </menu>
```

**in activity**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
    final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search1);
    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
    searchView.setQueryHint("Search Name");
    searchView.setIconified(false);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MenuItemCompat.getActionView(MenuItem item) is deprecated in API level 26.1.0.

Now the recommended way is calling getActionView() directly on the menu item:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search); 
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();

    // ...
}
```

Comment: i have tried, but the searchView is still return null.